# Unable to show Play Store in-app Update Dialog

Tags: android, google-play

I'm looking into In-App Updates by Play Store API. I followed the examples in the Documentations, and some other articles. But I still can't get it to show the Update Dialog provided by Play Store.

I've seen some apps do it, show a dialog to prompt the user to start the update, but using a `FakeAppUpdateManager` doesn't seem to do it.

Do I have to use a real release to test it out? Or is there some configuration for `FakeAppUpdateManager` that I need to do?

```
private fun checkForUpdates() {
    val appUpdateManager = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        FakeAppUpdateManager(this).apply {
            setUpdateAvailable(UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
            setUpdatePriority(5)
        }
    } else {
        AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)
    }

    // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
    val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo

    // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
        if (
            appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE &&
            // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
            appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
        ) {
            // Create a listener to track request state updates.
            val listener = { state: InstallState ->
                // (Optional) Provide a download progress bar.
                if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADING) {
                    val bytesDownloaded = state.bytesDownloaded()
                    val totalBytesToDownload = state.totalBytesToDownload()
                    // Show update progress bar.
                }
                // Log state or install the update.
            }

            // Before starting an update, register a listener for updates.
            appUpdateManager.registerListener(listener)

            // Request the update.
            appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
                appUpdateInfo,
                // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
                AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE,
                // The current activity making the update request.
                this,
                // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                UPDATE_RC,
            )

            // When status updates are no longer needed, unregister the listener.
//                appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(listener)
        }
    }
}
```

https://ibb.co/BLCKmnx

Comment: you must need to release in one of the channel - alpha, beta or public.

Comment: Does Internal App Sharing work?

Comment: yes it will be work

Answer (score 0):

`FakeAppUpdataManager` is very rudimentary and will not show any UI or even invoke activity's onActivityResult based on my experience of testing and looking into decompiled code of it:

[image]

(please notice activity is not passed any further, thus no way to further do onActivityResult call by the manager)

What you can and should do though, is to check `isConfirmationDialogVisible` for `AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE` scenario and `isImmediateFlowVisible` for `AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE` scenario - but these dialogs/flows will never be shown on UI.

Example sequence for former:

```
            assert(fakeAppUpdateManager.isConfirmationDialogVisible)

            fakeAppUpdateManager.userAcceptsUpdate()
            fakeAppUpdateManager.downloadStarts()
            fakeAppUpdateManager.downloadCompletes()

            assert(fakeAppUpdateManager.isInstallSplashScreenVisible)

            fakeAppUpdateManager.installCompletes()
```

Example sequence for latter:

```
            assert(fakeAppUpdateManager.isImmediateFlowVisible)

            fakeAppUpdateManager.userAcceptsUpdate()
            fakeAppUpdateManager.downloadStarts()
            fakeAppUpdateManager.downloadCompletes()

            assert(fakeAppUpdateManager.isInstallSplashScreenVisible)

            fakeAppUpdateManager.installCompletes()
```